# Conversion of upper triangle linear index from index on symmetrical array

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices

Say we have a symmetrical matrix of the following form:

```
A = [[0,1,2],
     [1,0,2],
     [2,2,0]]
```

If we take the upper triangle of `A` and flatten it we get:

```
B = [0,1,2,0,2,0]
```

Is there a known formula that could take an index for `A` in the form of `(i,j)` and convert it to a value `k` that corresponds to the location in `B` for that index. For example:

```
A[0,1] = B[1] = 1 
A[1,0] = B[1] = 1
A[2,0] = B[2] = 2
A[2,1] = B[4] = 2
```

In addition what is the method for deriving this formula? Perhaps my brain just isn't working today, but I can't seem to remember how to go about doing this.

I have found something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27086195/linear-index-upper-triangular-matrix), but that is for the triangle with an offset of 1 and I would like to include the diagonal in my conversion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the dimension is $N$, then $$n = \frac{N(N-1)}2 - \frac{(N-i)(N-i-1)}2 +j$$ works.

Specifically, if $N = 3$ as in your example, then $$n = 3 - \frac{(3 - i)(2-i)}2 + j$$

This assumes that $j \ge i$. If $j < i$, then reverse the roles of $i$ and $j$ in the formula (which works since $A$ is symmetric).

Comment: Could you explain how this formula is derived?

Comment: Mostly by playing around until I got it to work right. $j$ was obviously just going to be added to some expression for $i$. That expression needed to be the sum of all values between $i$ and $N - 1$. The formula for the sum of all numbers up to a value $k$ is well-known ($k(k+1)/2$), So I needed the difference between $k = N-1$ and $k = i -1$

Comment: @Petahanks - though your post has been deleted (since it was a question and should have been asked as a question, not an answer), and I was unaware of it until now, I'll still address your concern. Note the last sentence in my answer. Your "wrong" values had $j < i$, but the formula is for $j \ge i$. So of course you got the wrong answer.

Comment: is this answer correct?

Comment: Yes. If you are having problems, please note that as per the OP, $i, j$ range from $0$ to $N-1$, not $1$ to $N$. Also note the final line of the answer.

Comment: What is the equation if I do not want to include the diagonal? If B is `B = [1,2,2]` and `A[0,1] = B[0] = 1 ` ??